# Twitter API call works perfectly in raw PHP, returns 'page does not exist' in Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm coming back to a custom plugin I wrote for a client a few months ago. It uses [Abraham Williams' Twitter oAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to pull tweets from their timeline at hourly intervals, and then 'caches' the results in the Wordpress database (so that the Twitter app isn't called upon for every page visit).

This *was* working perfectly, but appears to have stopped. What's now blowing my mind is that, if I separate the function out into a 'raw' standalone PHP page, it still works exactly as it should, throwing out a JSON object of tweets. However, as soon as I put it back into my Wordpress plugin, even with *identical code*, the Twitter API returns:

```
{ message="Sorry, that page does not exist", code=34}
```

I've included an example of the standalone PHP file versus the (virtually identical) function in the Wordpress plugin [in this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uY0hyqex).

**To confirm:** all of the `get_option()` calls return the correct information with regards to keys, tokens and secrets. I've debugged it to death and cannot for the life of me see what's going on. Also worth noting that both the standalone file and Wordpress are running on the exact same installation (which, in this instance, is xampp-powered localhost running PHP 5.4+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out that the Twitter username I was trying to pull actually started with a capital `T` (rather than the whole username being lowercase, as was in my code).

Again, I can determine *no reason* for this, but: when my code was in a standalone file, the Twitter API call was apparently case insensitive, so it worked even when the username was passed as all lowercase. As soon as I put it into my Wordpress plugin - working on the same enviroment - it returned that wholly confusing `code 34` error, because the username I was passing didn't start with a capital `T`.

Moral of the story: **CHECK YOUR CASE.**